# posting on wordpress using python

Tags: python, wordpress, networking

It is my first attempt of any internet application. I am trying to post on my blog from a text document in my PC using python. My code is here

```
f = open('proofs.txt') 
data = f.readline()
print data
import wordpresslib
url = 'http://www.agnsa.wordpress.com/xmlrpc.php'
wp = wordpresslib.WordPressClient(url,'agnsa','pan@13579')
wp.selectBlog(0)
post = wordpresslib.WordPressPost()
post.title = 'try'
post.description = data
idPost = wp.newPost(post,True)
```

After running the module it is giving the error that connection failed to server. Here is the response. I tried to find about it but i couldnt understand how i can solve it. I never develop any such application before. It is simple but i cant understand what to do now.... Can any one give me suggestion what to do ??

Error is :

```
[Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did
not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed
because connected host has failed to respond
```

Answer (score 4):

A few pointers to help you troubleshoot:

1. The domain http://www.agnsa.wordpress.com/ does not exist. Is this correct?
2. On wordpress, XMLRPC is not turned on by default. Go to Settings->Writing->Remote Publishing and check the box for XML-RPC on your account. [More info on XML-RPC Support](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support).
3. **EDITED** The correct path for XML RPC on wordpress, since you have a domain `agneesa.wordpress.com` would be `http://agneesa.wordpress.com/wordpress/xmlrpc.php`. [See section on Endpoint](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support).
4. Have you just published your password? StackOverflow has a trustworthy and helpful community. But I am not sure I would trust the rest of the world :)

If you have enable XML-RPC on the server side and the address in your comment is correct, then this code should work:

```
import wordpresslib

# dummy data to be on safe side
data = "Post content, just ensuring data is not empty"

url='http://agneesa.wordpress.com/wordpress/xmlrpc.php'
# insert correct username and password
wp=wordpresslib.WordPressClient(url,'agnsa','pan@13579')
wp.selectBlog(0)
post=wordpresslib.WordPressPost()
post.title='try'
post.description=data
idPost=wp.newPost(post,True)
```

The latest error suggests you cannot make a connection. It is either due to the wrong address in your code, or due to a failure on the side of the server (not accepting the connection for some reason). The same error was discussed in other questions on SO, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136033/python-soap-xmlhttprequest), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9019134/httpconnection-request-socket-gaierror-in-python),  and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860200/python-scraper-socket-error-breaks-script-if-target-is-404d) -- while they do not relate to the library you are using, browsing the answers and related questions may be helpful in giving you leads.

Comment: http://www.agneesa.wordpress.com/   it is correct and it exist...

ohh let me try the XML .. no this password isnt write ;)

Comment: I did wht u have said and now the it is giving me this error :/
now i have to try something else ... IS MY CODE RIGHT OR I AM MISSING SOMETHING?? 

File "socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

Comment: @lara I have added some more ideas to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: thanks a lot .. 
it is giving the same error
i m using proxy server so do u thing it can cause this error??

Comment: Possibly. Something is getting in the way of your connection with the wordpress server... Do some research on that line? Others may be able to help if you ask a specific question on your set up.

Comment: ok ..let me ask a question in other way 
thank u so much fr u time :)